# why URLFetch is slow when encapsulated by module and how to fix it

Tags: performance-tuning, scoping, internet

I'm using *Mathematica 10.0.2* on Win7.

I'm writing some program to crawl etymology of words on http://www.etymonline.com/. Below lies the example code:

```
str = URLFetch[
"http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=" <>
 "droll"] // Evaluate; 
etymonlinestr = 
StringJoin@
StringSplit[
StringCases[str, "<dt" ~~ ___ ~~ "<!-- DICTIONARY -->"], {"<", ">"}][[1, 2 ;; -1 ;; 2]];
StringJoin@StringSplit[etymonlinestr, "\n"][[1 ;; 2]]
```

It seems work well. the code above produce:

> "droll (adj.) 1620s, from French drôle \"odd, comical, funny\" \
>   (1580s), in Middle French a noun meaning \"a merry fellow,\" possibly
>   \ from Middle Dutch drol \"fat little fellow, goblin,\" or Middle High
>   \ German trolle \"clown,\" ultimately from Old Norse troll \"giant, \
>   troll\" (see troll (n.)). Related: Drolly; drollish."

However, when I decided to write a function for future convenience：

```
searchforetymonline01[wordstr_] :=
Module[{str, etymonlinestr},
str = URLFetch[
 "http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=" <> wordstr] // Evaluate; 
etymonlinestr = 
StringJoin@
StringSplit[
  StringCases[str, "<dt" ~~ ___ ~~ "<!-- DICTIONARY -->"], {"<", 
   ">"}][[1, 2 ;; -1 ;; 2]];
StringJoin@StringSplit[etymonlinestr, "\n"][[1 ;; 2]]
]
```

Then strange things happen: running something like `searchforetymonline01["drenched"]` became extremely slow and I have to quit *Mathematica* to kill its progress.

why will this happen? when the code suspends forever if with just a `Module` covered?

Comment: `First@AbsoluteTiming[searchforetymonline01["drenched"]]` gives me around 0.5 secs.

Comment: I also don't see a slowdown; the search for "drenched" returns the correct results and takes only 0.3s on my system this morning. I am on MMA 10.3 on Win7-64.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this problem in 10.1.0 under Windows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced.  This may be caused by a localized configuration issue and may be impossible to solve without additional details.

Answer (score 2):

You might check for `"StatusCode"` before going on to do the parsing.

Also `ImportString[str,"HTML"]` will make the code a bit less intimidating.

Here's a slightly different approach to your function:

```
searchforetymonline01[wordstr_] := 
 Module[
    {statusCode, str, etymonlinestr,baseURL},
    baseURL = "http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search="; 
    {statusCode, str} = URLFetch[baseURL<>wordstr, {"StatusCode", "Content"}];
    If[statusCode == 200,
       (*then*)  
       StringJoin[ImportString[str, {"HTML", "Data"}][[2, 1 ;; 2]]]
       ,
       (*else*)
       $Failed
       ]
    ]
```